# Grab 2 items in 1 string?

Tags: python, regex

I'm not smart with this as u can tell.  I'm looking to grab 2 things with 1 line.

eg

```
<a href="(URL TO GRAB)">(TITLE TO GRAB)</a>
<a href="(URL TO GRAB)" rel="nofollow">(TITLE TO GRAB)</a>
```

The Urls and Titles always begin with http or https

```
<a href="http(s)://www.whatever.com/1.html">http(s)://www.whatever.com/1.html</a>
<a href="http(s)://www.whatever.com/2.html" rel="nofollow">http(s)://www.whatever.com/2.html</a>
```

I have tried the following with replace method to eliminate `rel="nofollow">` with a blank space but there are 130 some other `re="variables'>` and I only want the `"nofollow"` one and don't want to write 130 some replace.

```
item_infos=<a href="([^"]+)"([^"]+)</a>
item_order=url.tmp|title.tmp
item_skill=rss
```

It's python for kodi/xbmc scraping reddit.

Edit:
Thanks for your help folks.   I am currently using the one provided by Jon

```
item_infos=<a href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>([^<]+)</a>
```

Seems to work but i wont know till the thread is updated later.  Thanks again :)

Comment: Don't use regex for parsing HTML. It never ends well, and HTML parsers were created for a reason. Try out [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) as @mhawke recommended.

Comment: @pzp Ironically, BeautifulSoup admits to using a whole bunch of regexs to parse HTML. Though what you're saying is "generally" correct.

Comment: @PascalvKooten What I meant by that is don't roll your own. I trust that BeautifulSoup has done extensive testing and it's gotten enough use that any bugs would be reported and patched relatively quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HTML parser such as BeautifulSoup. Here's an example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a href="http(s)://www.whatever.com/1.html">http(s)://www.whatever.com/1.html</a>
<a href="http(s)://www.whatever.com/2.html" rel="nofollow">http(s)://www.whatever.com/2.html</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print 'href :', soup.a['href']
print 'title :', soup.a.text

for tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    print 'href: {}, title: {}'.format(tag['href'], tag.text)
```

**Output**

```
href : http(s)://www.whatever.com/1.html
title : http(s)://www.whatever.com/1.html
href: http(s)://www.whatever.com/1.html, title http(s)://www.whatever.com/1.html
href: http(s)://www.whatever.com/2.html, title http(s)://www.whatever.com/2.html
```

Comment: I think I've gone too deep for my rookieness. I don't believe the way I'm doing it I can write the beautifulsoup call.  Its a .cfg file

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to match anchors and extract the URL and display portions, something like this perhaps:

`item_infos=<a href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>([^<]+)</a>`